# Displayed format different than value

Tags: excel, function, custom-formatting

Using Excel Macros:

I am trying to create a function that takes a double called Feet and another called Inches and have it return the total number of inches. That is the easy part. I want it to then display the information in the cell like so:

5ft 8in

Here is the code that I have come up with:

```
Function FTIN(Feet As Double, Inches As Double) As Double
    'This part works fine.
    Dim total As Double

    total = (Feet * 12) + Inches

    FTIN = total

    'this part does not seem to work.
    Dim foot As Double
    Dim inch As Double

    foot = WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(total / 12, 0)
    inch = total - (foot * 12)

    result = foot & "ft " & inch & "in"
End Function
```

while it does return the the total number of inches it does not display it in the way I need it to.

I basically want it to do the same thing as dates where the value is 41361 but what is displayed is "3/28/2013".

Also I know I can make the value as 508 and I can make the custom format as 0"ft "00"in", but that would not give me a value that I can work with.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can customize formating in the way you want.  I would recomend making a second function that returns a string.  Plug the feet and inches into this new function, add text for "ft" and "in", and concatenate it all together (using the & operator).

Comment: Could you give me an example? What I think you are saying is to change it to FTIN = foot & "ft " & inch & "in". If so that will not work. I need to be able to use the values as numbers, not strings.

Comment: Is there really no answer to this? This might be the first time I have come across something in programming that really has no solution. That's sad.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with a worksheet formula, try this:

```
=INT(a1/12)&"ft  "&TRIM(TEXT(a1-INT(a1/12)*12,"# ???/???"))&"in"
```

where A1 is the cell with your UDF in it.